# Decoding RTP packets G.729

Tags: c#, rtp, decoding, packets

I have a byte array with RTP packets in it.

I am not using a SIP client, I just have the array.

Is there an option to decode the packets in g.729 and then record the voice and save it into a WAV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some help here:

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid5FF057FB1D01EBB06AE9B0DFF096CA01A572D167.aspx

Comment: Where can i find the dll for this code? I have a error that says that it cant find the g729 dll..

Answer (score 0):

you need a g.729 decoder for decoding the payload from the rtp packets. as far as i know audacity is capable of doing this job. extract the raw data from the rtp stream with wireshark and then decode the audio data ... this should work.

Comment: Thnaks, But the thing is I need to do it Programmatically (in C#).. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Write rtp byte array to a raw file. Then you can convert that file to mp3 by using ffmpeg.exe with g729 decode command.

```
ffmpeg.exe -f alaw -ar 8000  -i " + rawFile + ".raw " + rawFile + ".mp3
```

Above is the command to convert to mp3.

All the best.